# mysql gives NULL for record in a table if JOIN and COUNT used but SELECT works fine why?

Tags: mysql

Table 1

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `com_msg` (
 `msg_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `msg_to` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `msg_from` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `msg_new` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `msg_content` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
 `msg_date` date NOT NULL,
 `bl_sender` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `bl_recip` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`msg_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `msg_id` (`msg_id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Table 2

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ac_vars` (
 `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `ac_ballance` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `prof_views` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`user_id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I use query :

```
SELECT ac_ballance, prof_views, COUNT( msg_id ) AS messages
FROM ac_vars
INNER JOIN com_msg ON user_id = msg_to 
WHERE user_id =".$userid." AND com_msg.msg_new =1;
```

I get :

```
ac_ballance=NULL(incorrect)
prof_views=NULL(incorrect)
messages=0(correct)
```

But with Select statement just on ac_vars I get correct values, what is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: ac_ballance=0, prof_views=0,messages=0, as ac_vas has default value of 0

Comment: If there are no rows matching the `WHERE` clause, why do you expect non-null values in `ac_ballance` and `prof_views`? Those have to come from one of the matching rows, and there aren't any.

Comment: The thing is on localhost it works as expected "gives number values for ac_vars" but for some reason on live server gives NULL values" same DB, Server, structure etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want rows from the table `ac_vars` even when there's no corresponding row in the table `com_msg`.
So you must use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT ac_ballance, prof_views, COUNT( msg_id ) AS messages
FROM ac_vars
LEFT JOIN com_msg 
ON user_id = msg_to AND com_msg.msg_new =1
WHERE user_id =".$userid.";
```

Please note that the condition

```
com_msg.msg_new =1
```

got to be a part of the `JOIN` condition and not the `WHERE` clause, because there's no value in com_msg that fulfills this condition.

**Note**

Adding

```
GROUP BY ac_ballance, prof_views
```

is not needed by MySQLs optimization because the values in those columns are directly dependent of the `user_id` and the `WHERE` clause permits only one single row.

Comment: But I still dont understand why it works on localhost even though is incorrect ?

Comment: @bart Can't say without knowing your data. But usually I don't try to explain why a faulty approach returns the desired data.